# copy or rsync in numeric sequence/order

Tags: shell, rsync, cp

I have a huge set of image files, unfortunately in an unpadded numeric sequence, that I need to copy over in the format:

```
IMG_1.jpg
IMG_2.jpg
...
IMG_500000.jpg
```

The problem is that all the file operations seem to operate in the order:

```
IMG_1.jpg
IMG_10.jpg
IMG_100.jpg
IMG_1000.jpg
IMG_10000.jpg
...
IMG_2.jpg
IMG_20.jpg
IMG_200.jpg
IMG_2000.jpg
IMG_20000.jpg
...
```

Is there any way to copy or rsync a specific range of images? For example: `IMG_1.jpg - IMG_5000.jpg` without everything else?

The only thing I can think of is manually building this list into a txt file and passing that in, but was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: so you want to copy only file names between img_1.jpg thru img_5000.jpg? `cp img_[1-9].jpg img_[1-9][0-9].jpg img[1-9][0-9][0-9].jpg img[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg targDir` should get you very close. Likely to run into an error like `cmd line too long`. Good luck.

Comment: @waffl : You tagged your question as _shell_, which means that you are searching for a POSIX shell solution. I don't think that this can be done, as even the `{1..5000}` notation suggested by dash-o and bbotte would not work there. If you are willing to switch to Zsh, you could use `img_<1..5000>.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming limit on number of files per call, consider using seq/xargs to split the copy into blocks (e.g., 50 files per call)

```
seq -f 'IMG_%.0f.jpg' 5000 | xargs -L50 cp -t /target
```

If command line length not an issue

```
cp IMG_{1..5000}.jpg /target
```